# Correlation failed for Blazor App with Multiple Organization Authentication via ngrok

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor

I start a new Blazor App that says Source: .NET Core 3.1.4 and select Work or School Accounts and in my case picked Multiple Organizations for Authentication. I let Visual Studio provision the app for authentication.

I then run the application in Visual Studio and get the local Url

I then run ngrok with something like:

ngrok http https://localhost:5001 -host-header="localhost:5001"

also tried IIS with

ngrok http https://localhost:44389 -host-header="localhost:44389"

When I try to access the site via the ngrok supplied URL and after I provide my credentials in the AAD organizational login I get the following error:

Exception: Correlation failed.
Unknown location

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()

Exception: An error was encountered while handling the remote login.
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler.HandleRequestAsync()
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

I would like to know if there is a way to get this to work or at least understand why it will not or cannot work. I read quite a few articles online and tried various same site cookie policies, additional redirect uris in the azure portal and a few other things and never came up with a combination that allowed the site to be accessed via ngrok.